# Undefined name "Firebase" following "FlutterFire Overview" tutorial

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart

I follow this page : https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/overview/#initializing-flutterfire

Then I type the instruction:

```
await Firebase.initializeApp();
```

Like in the documentation, I have the error: `'Undefined name 'Firebase'`. However, I the import is present in my file:

```
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
```

Plus, when I type `FirebaseApp` in place of `Firebase`, FirebaseApp is recognized but not define initializeApp function.

Note that import is displayed as greyed `import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';`

So Where is the problem ?

Comment: can you add version of `firebase_core` that is installed in your pubspec.yaml?

Comment: Try using `flutter pub get` in your terminal. Did you install the firebase package?

Comment: firebase_core: ^0.4.0+9

Comment: @coutiereric yep, and you are reading documentation for ^0.7.0, change it to `firebase_core: "^0.7.0"`

Comment: @Devilscomrade what do you want to say for "Did you install the firebase package" ?

Comment: I just saw your answer to Simon, nevermind my questions.

Comment: @SimonSot Now it works. I've changed my pubspec.yaml to the last version of each package:
  firebase_core: ^1.0.0
  firebase_auth: ^1.0.1
  cloud_firestore: ^1.0.3
What I have supposed to do now ? Edit my question or answer to it ?

Comment: If everything works, you can answer to your question yourself, or I can do it, as you like. Keep in mind that ^1.0.0 firebase packages are null-safety. If you are not ready for it I advise using ^0.7.0 until they update documentation.

Answer (score 0):

I've changed the version of each Firebase related packages to the latest ones (because, as suggested, the tutorial is for a new version than 0.4.0) and all works fine.

```
firebase_core: ^1.0.0
firebase_auth: ^1.0.1
cloud_firestore: ^1.0.3
```